# Can't run server side script using jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Firstly, thanks so much in advance for any help you might be able to give me on this!

Right, what I want to do, is to call a php script to run server side, which takes in a single value (which will be an email) and write it to a text file.

This is the .php file that I want run. I haven't added any of the email functionality, but after hours of trying I can't even seem to get it to create a text file and directory. If I run it in the IDE, it runs perfectly, it creates the script and displays the "test me" text at the bottom. However, when It runs from the jquery call, all it does it read the text at the bottom of the file. This is where I call it in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#emailForm").submit(function()
        {
            alert("Beginning jquery");
            $("#div1").load("handleEmailAddresses.php");
            alert("Load called");
            //$.post("handleEmailAddresses.php");
        });
```

I've also tried the post function you can see commented out. Nothing works. Here is the php file that is called:

```
<html> 

<?php

 $dir = 'myDir';
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) 
 {
    mkdir ($dir, 0777);//This just gives me r/w access to the folder
 }

 file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.txt', 'Hello File');

 ?>
Test Text
</html>
```

Please help, its killing me! Thanks so much!

Comment: is the PHP script error'ing? what happens if you access it directly from a browser

Comment: also try adding a preventDefault() to the function, otherwise the form is still getting submitted and the page is reloading

Comment: Thanks jye265, When I access the address from the browser it just loads as plain text :?

Comment: If I save the php file as html and load it, it just displays the text - "test me"

Comment: What is the plain text that displays? try wrapping the file_put_contents in a var_dump() to check that it isnt failing to access the file

Comment: I'll do that now, thanks

Comment: So i've done that. The file is created perfectly well when I run the php script from my IDE, however it the php doesn't run when called from the browser!?!?

Comment: does the php file have a .php extension? and do other php scripts run on the same server? is php setup properly

Comment: how are you accessing the script? to make php scripts run they need to be requested through a server, does the url start with localhost? or are you opening the file directly into the browser

Comment: jye I think that is the problem, I wasn't aware I needed to run them through a server. Will sort that out now, that must be the problem! Thanks, sorry for being a n00b, new to webdesign!

Comment: not a problem, have a quick google on setting up apache and php on your computer and hope you can get it all up and running

Comment: Jye, thanks so much I really appreciate it, all the way on the other side of the world you have completely made someone's day! best, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try Ajax

```
$.ajax({
      url : '/handleEmailAddresses.php',
  });
```

and if you want to check also:

```
     $.ajax({
        url : '/handleEmailAddresses.php',
     }).done(function() {
        console.log('completed');
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Script and try

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#emailForm").submit(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Beginning jquery");
           $("#div1").load("handleEmailAddresses.php", function(response, status, xhr)                    {
                 if (status == "error") 
                 {
                  var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                  alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    alert("Load Compleated");
                 }
           });
        });
```

**PHP :**

```
 <?php

     $dir = 'myDir';
     if ( !file_exists($dir) ) 
     {
       if (!mkdir($dir, 0)) {
            echo('Failed to create folders...');
            exit;
       }
     }
 $r = file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.txt', 'Hello File');

 if ($r)
     echo "Success";
 else
    echo "Error";
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Champ, I've replaced mine with this, and annoyingly it says "Load completed".

Comment: which means that it must be something wrong with my php file?

Comment: yes. so now you can change you php file to the content i provided  remove every thing else.